# Meaning and use of とっさに

Tags: meaning, words

Could you please give me some example sentences with とっさに? According to my dictionary, it means "quickly", but my dictionary doesn't give me any example sentence, so I don't know exactly how to use this word.

When do I use とっさに instead of other expressions like 速く、急に、急速に or さっと?

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

とっさに is semantically more like "without thinking", "instinctively", "instantly" or "reflexively". It's commonly used with an action to protect someone (physically or socially). Examples:

- 前方に人影が見えたのでとっさにブレーキを踏んだ。
- 叱られると思い、とっさに嘘をついてしまった。
- 彼の顔は知っているが、名前はとっさには思い出せなかった。

It's almost never interchangeable with 急に.

とっさの means "happened in a very short time" and its connotation is "no time to think".

- とっさの出来事だったのでうまく対応できなかった。
- とっさの判断だったが、結果的にはうまく行った。

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It has been really helpful! :)